# Performance comparison of using Hibernate + EhCache, EhCache or NoSql

Tags: hibernate, nosql, ehcache

I currently use Hibernate with H2 for my music tagging application, the primary reason for using hibernate is to stop memory usage increasing in proportion to number of files tagged, which it would if all processing was stored in memory rather than disk.

On of the things I use Hibernate for is to download metadata from online database, then if application needs to use that metadata again they can retrieve locally form Hibernate rather than a slower redownload from the web.

Application works fine on PC with good performance but I am now trying to improve performance on slower nas devices, and performance is dragged down by slow cpus and disk i/o.

This led me to look at Hibernates second level cache, i.e I allocated a small amount of memory to Ehcache and then application looks there before Hibernate lookup, this has improved performance.

It has got me thinking, since the metadata lookup is only by primary key, (there are no other types of queries) am I making a mistake using Hibernate for such data. Would it make more sense to just use Ehcache directly for this type of data, or would I be better of using a NoSql database.

It basically comes down to cpu performance, but I have not been able to find comparable benchmarks. I am hoping that someone with more experience in this area than be can give me a view on the likely performance results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Hibernate indeed. Unless you want to persist the data for some other time, using a cache is the right solution.

So just raw Ehcache will be perfect and the fastest option. But do a benchmark and tune your settings.

Comment: So data will be kept in cache (room permitting) whilst application running, but then freed when application stopped, yes I think this would be better for this type of data. But I also have other data that does need to be persisted but again we only look up by id (i.e Song which is representation of file metadata), do you think it would be worth looking at nosql db or sticking with Hibernate for this type of data ?

Comment: Don't go crazy on your architecture. If you already have a RDBMS, use it. No need to add a NoSQL brick in the mix. It will only complicate your architecture for no benefit. Response time will be similar.